# Understanding a rule related to Young tableau

Tags: representation-theory

This is my first time learning Young tableau, and I am struggling with a specific rule.
I am reading it from [this lecture note](http://pcteserver.mi.infn.it/%7Eferrera/teaching/young_tableaux.pdf).

The rule I am confused about is the very last point at the end of page 2. I have pasted a screenshot of it here for easy reference. Could someone explain a bit more why the tableau shown in the last sub-bullet point should be rejected? It says that the going from right to left for each row, the number of $b$'s should not be more than the $a$'s, but in this specific tableau there are one each of $a$ and $b$. So, why is it not allowed? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren’t considering the phrase “at any given box position”. Starting on the right of the first row with $b$, at *that* position there has been one $b$ and zero $a$’s, which is forbidden.

Comment: Ah okay. I was actually confused about that phrase. Thank you very much for clarifying this.

Comment: Just so that I am clear about the phrase, does it mean you consider the first row and look at the rightmost box, and it must always be $a$. But now if you go to the second row and consider the rightmost box, that can be $b$ cause there was already a row (the first row) which has an $a$ at the position. Correct?

Comment: Yes. Look at the $SU(3)$ example on page 4.